# Is it possible to create custom columns for PAGE module in TYPO3?

Tags: layout, module, typo3, backend

In a fresh installation of V8 TYPO3, there are four columns: left, normal, right and border. I would like to tweak this less columns and with custom names.

How can I achieve this? And once I do have these columns, how can I reference them in typoscript: normal way would be styles.content.get.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that using the "backend layout" records.

Here you will find an old tutorial that can introduce you to the topic:

http://typo3buddy.com/typo3-template-tutorial/fluid/backend-layout/

Please note that you can as well store the backend layouts in text files and use these to change the fluid template file that renders your page in frontend

- here is a very basic tutorial (sorry, in italian) http://www.newtvision.com/blog/post/come-includere-backend-layout-su-ts-file/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering how how can I get the styled content then? styles.content.getRight is not working in this case.

Comment: I wrote 
`20 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
   orderBy = sorting
   where = colPos=2
  }
 }`
It seems to be working :)

Comment: @Akimbas  `styles.content.getLeft`, `styles.content.getRight` and `styles.content.getBorder` have been removed in TYPO3 7 and above.
Of course you can "recover" them just copying `styles.content.get` and changing the `colPos` value. See also https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/Installation/Upgrading/Index.html